# Add remote method to GridView event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, event-handling, reusability

I have an aspx web app that has multiple GridView's with similar methods. My thought was to create a "helper" class that has the reusable methods. My question is what is the best way to utilize those remote class methods?

the frontend doesn't accept the class.method like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="myGridView" ... OnSorting="myClass.reusableMethod"
```

Visual Studio didn't give me any compiling errors when I attached the handler on Page_Load, but I did get a runtime error saying the GridView tried to fire the event and it wasn't there.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    myGridView.Sorting += myClass.reusableMethod;
}
```

The final way I am pretty sure will work, but seems counter-productive. Creating the method on the pages backend like normal but then having the only line being a call to the remote method

```
public void myGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    myClass.reusableMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done. First remove the `OnSorting` event from the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="true">
```

Then only bind the method outside the `IsPostBack` check.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //do not bind the event here
    }

    //but here
    myGridView.Sorting += myClass.reusableMethod;
}
```

Now you can use the Method

```
public static void reusableMethod(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;
}
```

Comment: doesn't !IsPostBack basically mean the first time hitting the page? Why would that not work? Or does the gridview lose the handler on a postback? Thus the code doesn't re-add the handler after a postback?

Comment: Yes it does. But since you are binding an event dynamically you need to do that on every page load or it is lost on PostBack. And if it is lost it will not trigger.

Comment: ok I wasn't aware it would lose assignment on postbacks. That makes sense now. Thank you!